# Complexification of proper scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a proper scheme over $\mathbb{C}$.

We define $X_{\mathbb{R}}$ to be a scheme over $\mathbb{R}$, which is the same topological space as $X$ with structure sheaf generated by real and imaginary parts of functions on $X$. Note that $2 \dim X = \dim X_{\mathbb{R}}$

Finally let $$X_{\mathbb{C}} := X_{\mathbb{R}} \times_{Spec\mathbb{R}} Spec \mathbb{C}$$
So $X_{\mathbb{C}}$ is just base change of $X_{\mathbb{R}}$.

**Question:** Let $X$ be a proper scheme. Does $X_{\mathbb{C}}$ have to be proper?

If it is possible to give an explicit description for $X_{\mathbb{C}}$ or at least work out example of $\mathbb{CP}^1$ it would be great.

Comment: The construction you call $X_\mathbb{R}$ is known as the [Weil restriction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_restriction) of $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Why should $X_{\mathbb R}$ be a scheme? It is a ringed space, I don't see any evident reason for it to be a scheme.